# How do you get an indentation after ::before pseudo element?

Tags: html, css

I have a table and I want to use the CSS ::before pseudo element with a counter to add a row number to the first `td` of every row. My issue is that if the first td wraps the second line starts under the number, and I would like it to start inline with the text above it. Can this be done with just CSS?

Example:

[image: Image example of what I would like to accomplish.]

**Edit**

https://jsfiddle.net/3yL19zde/

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some really long text that wraps to a second line...</td>
    <td>Some other column</td>
    <td>A third column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some really long text that wraps to a second line...</td>
    <td>Some other column</td>
    <td>A third column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 480px;
}

table td {
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

table tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would insert the pseudo-element at the beginning of the row instead of inside the first cell, so that it can be displayed as an independent `table-cell`:

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
}
tr {
  counter-increment: row;
}
tr::before {
  content: counter(row);
  display: table-cell;
  font-weight: bold;
}
tr::before, td {
  border: 1px dotted #888;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some really long text that wraps to a second line...</td>
    <td>Some other column</td>
    <td>A third column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some really long text that wraps to a second line...</td>
    <td>Some other column</td>
    <td>A third column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I didn't know about `display: table-cell`, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Note `display: table-cell` is not completely indispensable. If you don't use it, the pseudo-element will be wrapped inside an anonymous table-cell according to [anonymous table objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes), so the text will still be "indented" like you want. But for styling purposes it's easier if the pseudo-element is the cell box itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it inside the same cell (using `text-indent` and some padding).

```css
table {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
    width: 480px;
}
td {
    border: 1px dotted #888;
}
td:first-child {
    padding-left: 2em;
    text-indent: -2em;
}
td:first-child:before {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: 0;
    width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some really long text that wraps to a second line...</td>
        <td>Some other column</td>
        <td>A third column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some really long text that wraps to a second line...</td>
        <td>Some other column</td>
        <td>A third column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```